# Closed form expression for the following Binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation-method

I have the following Binomial expansion which I want to bound tightly. I have been able to bound but it is very loose. My method is as follows :-

$2\sum_{i=1}^{k/2} {n \choose n/2 +i} + {n \choose n/2}=2\left[ {n \choose n/2 +1} +{n \choose n/2 +2} \ldots +{n \choose n/2 +k/2} \right] + {n \choose n/2}$

$=2\left[ {n+1 \choose n/2 +2} +{n+1 \choose n/2 +4} \ldots +{n+1 \choose n/2 +k/2} \right] + {n \choose n/2}~~~~~$  (Combining 2 terms using ${n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}={n+1 \choose k}$)

$\ge 2 \left[{n+1 \choose n/2 +3} + {n+1 \choose n/2 +4 } \ldots {n+1 \choose n/2 +k/2 -1} + {n+1 \choose n/2 +k/2} \right] + {n \choose n/2}~~~~~~~$ (Using the inequality ${n+1 \choose n/2+k+1}\ge {n+1 \choose n/2+k}$)

$\ge 2{n+\log k \choose n/2 + k/2} + {n \choose n/2}$

Is it possible to have a tighter bound for this summation than what I obtained?

Comment: Keep going, you reduce the number of terms each time. Just be careful if the number of terms is odd.